# Getting Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'jqxmaskedinput'

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

This is part of a mvc 3 razor view. I have a few editorfor boxes on the form and wanted to add a bit of jquery to enhance the robustness of the form. However I am getting an odd error and it does not make sense to me.

First lets have a look at the view.

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/content/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css"/>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/content/site9.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.base.css")" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.darkblue.css")" type="text/css" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript">    </script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/jqwidgets/jqxcore.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/jqwidgets/jqxvalidator.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/jqwidgets/globalization/globalize.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/jqwidgets/jqxmaskedinput.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/jqwidgets/jqxinput.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/jqwidgets/gettheme.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#date_paid').datepicker();
    $("#first_name").jqxInput({ placeHolder: "First Name", width: 200, height: 25, theme: 'darkblue' });
    $("#last_name").jqxInput({ placeHolder: "Last Name", width: 200, height: 25, theme: 'darkblue' });
    $("#middle_initial").jqxInput({ placeHolder: "Middle Initial", width: 150, height: 25, theme: 'darkblue' });
    $("#zip_code").jqxmaskedinput({ mask: '#####-####', width: 150, height: 25, theme: 'darkblue' });

});
```

```
<div class="editor-label">
        <label>First Name</label>
        @Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.first_name)
        @Html.ValidationMessage("first_name", "*")

       <label class="small_spacing">Middle Initial</label>
        @Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.middle_initial)
        @Html.ValidationMessage("middle_initial", "*")

       <label class="small_spacing">Last Name</label>
        @Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.last_name)
        @Html.ValidationMessage("last_name", "*")
    </div>
         <div class="editor-label">
    <label>City</label>
        @Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.city)
        @Html.ValidationMessage("city", "*")

    <label class="spacing">State</label>
      @Html.DropDownListFor(Function(model) model.State, New SelectList(ViewBag.states), New With {.class = "StateDrop"})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model)model.State)

    <label class="small_spacing">Zip Code</label>
        @Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.zip_code)
        @Html.ValidationMessage("zip_code", "*")
    </div>
```

All this looks great however that jqxmaskedinput is throwing the below error.

```
   Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'jqxmaskedinput'
```

And the jqxInput boxes are working fine. If I remove the jqxInput boxes the jqxmaskedInput works fine. I thought this was possibly a compatibility issue between the 2 but on jqWidgets I found an example that uses both jqxInput and jqxmaskedInput so there is little probability that this is a compatibility issue. Being a total nooblet in this area I am lost as to what may be the cause for this.. Any suggestions are welcomed..

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mean `jqxMaskedInput`? <-- note case

Comment: Wow this is a new one to me.. Apparently javascript is picky about the order that methods are called based on the order that the javascript files are loaded.

Comment: I figured it out I had to move the ` $("#zip_code").jqxMaskedInput({ mask: '#####-####', width: 150, height: 25, theme: 'darkblue' });` up so that it followed the load order of the javascript files.. Dunno why its that picky but it worked.

Comment: Javascript doesn't care what order you put them in, as long as the jqxmaskedinput.js file was loaded before the call to `.jqxMaskedInput`. Likely, you fixed it by changing the case without realizing it (look at your code above and you can see it is all lower case).

Comment: @ShadowCreeper You are the winner on this one. Good catch. I was overlooking it because Intelisense was popping up with it during typing it and being a little too quick on the tab key got me.

Comment: Submit the answer so I can throw ya the cred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript is case sensitive. The call to `.jqxmaskedinput` should have been `.jqxMaskedInput`.